# POST isset but not echo'ing out

Tags: php, javascript, forms, post, if-statement

I have a form posting to a page and I have a weird problem getting the values from the `POST` data. As you can see, I can check to see if `image_id`, `vote` and `fb_id_form` are all set before I run the conditional.

The javascript alerts run so I know the three variables are set. But what I get is confusing. I get the first alert window that says 'worked'. And then I get two blank alert windows. How can the `fb_id_form` be 'set' (via the conditional) yet have no value when I try to alert them out?

```
if(isset($_POST['image_id']) && isset($_POST['vote']) && isset($_POST['fb_id_form'])){
    $image_id = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['image_id']);
    $vote = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['vote']);
    $fb_id_form = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['fb_id_form']);
    echo "<script>alert('worked');</script>";
    echo "<script>alert('".$fb_id_form."');</script>";
    echo "<script>alert('".$_POST['fb_id_form']."');</script>";
}
```

this is the form data (on the same page):

```
echo "<form method=\"post\" action=\"\">
<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"image_id\" value=\"".$id."\" />
<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"vote\" value=\"1\" />
<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"fb_id_form\" value\"".$fb_id."\" />
<input type=\"submit\" name=\"submitvote\" value=\"Vote\" />
</form>";
```

Here's the issue. I have echo'ed out an alert of $fb_id RIGHT before the form and it gives me the correct value. When I submit it, I suppose that value gets lost.

Comment: Have you tried putting $_POST['fb_id_form'] into the alert?  Or just echoing $_POST['fb_id_form'] by itself?

Comment: Are you actually connected to the database? If not, `mysqli->real_escape_string()` will return an empty string.

Comment: I am connected to the database, I will add more code...

Comment: I just added more code. I am connected to the database and it works alright since I can echo out the values from the database before I submit the form. It gets lost somewhere after the submit...

Comment: You can also do `isset(var1,var2,var3)` versus `isset(var1) && isset(var2)` jsut as an FYI

Comment: I hope you're not mixing `$fb_id_form` and `$fb_id`.

Comment: What do you mean exactly? $fb_id is the correct value that is being echo'ed out before the form submits. It has a value that is correct and then when it's posted it's gone. I've tested out $fb_id to make sure it's correct and it works. What do you mean exactly about 'mixing'?

Answer (score 3):

Because `isset` will still be true if `$_POST['fb_id_form']` contains an empty string. You want to use `empty()`

[isset vs empty link](http://itslennysfault.com/php-isset-vs-empty)

> empty is quite a bit different than isset. First of all, the most obvious thing is that it works in the opposite way of isset, but there is much more to it than that. Empty will return true for everything isset would return false for PLUS it will also return true for an empty string, an empty array, the string "0″, the number 0, or false.

Answer (score 2):

A variable is set (`isset()` is true) when it is assigned and not NULL. This implies that a variable containing an empty string ("") *is*, in fact, set. See [documentation](http://php.net/isset).

To check if the variable is empty, use [`empty()`](http://php.net/empty), or check with `$mystr === ""`.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting these results because `isset()` returns true even if the only thing stored in the variable is an empty string. It's possible that your results aren't being stored. This could be due to the fact that your forms possibly have an action that restores the page which empties the fields leaving your variables with an empty string? We would have to see your html code in order to give a more thorough answer...

Answer (score 1):

[From the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php):

> isset — Determine if a variable is set and is not NULL

No where it says that it will return false if the variable is `""`, `0`, `false` etc. In your example it is easy to bypass your *sanity checks* by posting this data:

```
image_id=&vote=&fb_id_form=
```

You need additional data validation and you could use [PHP filter functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.filter.php) for this. Example code that checks if `$_POST` contains the three parameters, and they are integers:

```
$params = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST, array(
'image_id'   => array('filter' => FILTER_VALIDATE_INT, 'options' => array('default' => NULL)),
'vote'       => array('filter' => FILTER_VALIDATE_INT, 'options' => array('default' => NULL)),
'fb_id_form' => array('filter' => FILTER_VALIDATE_INT, 'options' => array('default' => NULL))
));
```

So for example someone posts this data to your page:

```
image_id=&vote=hello+world&fb_id_form=12345
```

Then the above code will return:

```
array(3) {
  ["image_id"]=>
  NULL
  ["vote"]=>
  NULL
  ["fb_id_form"]=>
  int(12345)
}
```

PS: `mysqli->real_escape_string` does not validate your data.

Comment: So use GET values instead of POST values? Am I understanding correctly?

Comment: No I never said that. Do not get confused with the "query string" like code I used. Data _POSTed_ to the server looks exactly like a query string.

Comment: Ok, so this is in reference to somebody posting data to my page? I guess I'm more interested in why fb_id_form is returning no value but image_id and vote are. Am I understanding correctly?

Comment: It could simply be because an empty string was passed as the value for fb_id_form. (i) Empty string is not the same as NULL/not set (ii) `$a = ""; var_dump(isset($a))` yields `true`.

Comment: Like I was saying, I echo out an alert of $fb_id right before the form (which is the value of the fb_id_form on the form) and it has an integer value. That's what is baffling me.

Answer (score 0):

i think it is something to do with the single quotes after and before the separation.

`echo "<script>alert(".$fb_id_form.");</script>";`

`echo "<script>alert(".$_POST['fb_id_form'].");</script>";`